# Auto-Clear Script - in Google Spreadsheet for all sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Sheets, I have a file that has multiple sheets in the same format that people fill out from all over the city.  I need a script that will clear out specific ranges in every sheet.

I was able to find a code that does what I need, but it is quite messy and will not be self sustainable if more sheets are added to it in the future.

Would someone be able to provide some opinions for me to make this better?  Perhaps something that will select all sheets and clear the range?

P.S. I have no script knowledge and kind of just studied articles all morning.

```
function clearRange() {
      // replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
      // replace 'dhrhrejYOURSHETIDerhe5j54j5j' with your actual sheet ID

var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1a7-uGrGaUK6uB5Sp-22N9kYYCB0EbpbHNzv8mYksLYY").getSheetByName('MONTREAL'); 
  sheetActive.getRange('6:500').clearContent();

var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1a7-uGrGaUK6uB5Sp-22N9kYYCB0EbpbHNzv8mYksLYY").getSheetByName('London'); 
  sheetActive.getRange('6:500').clearContent();

  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1a7-uGrGaUK6uB5Sp-22N9kYYCB0EbpbHNzv8mYksLYY").getSheetByName('OTTAWA'); 
  sheetActive.getRange('6:500').clearContent();
}
```

Comment: I recommend you complete some introductory JavaScript programming tutorials. Become familiar with `Array` and `Object` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a data architecture perspective, I would suggest gathering the data via a Google Form as opposed to many people editing the same spreadsheet.

However, if you just want code delete the same range on all sheets, I would suggest a loop that iterates through all the sheets. This should work for you.

```
var x = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1a7-uGrGaUK6uB5Sp-22N9kYYCB0EbpbHNzv8mYksLYY").getSheets()

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
  x[i].getRange('6:500').clearContent()    
}
```